# R gsub fixed pattern and non-fixed pattern at the same time

Tags: r, regex, data.table, gsub

I have a column in an R `data.table` of data with text like this:

```
> my_table
                           descr
   1:   DESCRIPTIONA - JONES:4:2
   2:  DESCRIPTIONB - WILDER:6:7
  ---                          
 253:    DESCRIPTIONA - MANN:5:8
 254: DESCRIPTIONB - ROBERTS:3:4
```

Notice there are two kinds of Descriptions: `DESCRIPTIONA` and `DESCRIPTIONB`. I want to replace the Whole description part including the names up to the first semi colon with `A` if it's `DESCRIPTIONA` and `B` if it's `DESCRIPTIONB`. That means I totally don't care about the name. The output should look something like this:

```
> my_table
      descr
   1: A:4:2
   2: B:6:7
  ---                          
 253: A:5:8
 254: B:3:4
```

I'm trying to use gsub to accomplish this, but I can't get the regex to replace just the part `(DESCRIPTIONA - JONES):4:2`. It's difficult because each name is different, and is of a different length. Any ideas?

Answer (score 5):

```
x = c(
    "DESCRIPTIONA - JONES:4:2",
    "DESCRIPTIONB - WILDER:6:7",
    "DESCRIPTIONA - MANN:5:8",
    "DESCRIPTIONB - ROBERTS:3:4"
)

gsub(pattern = "DESCRIPTION(.)[^:]*", replacement = "\\1", x)
# [1] "A:4:2" "B:6:7" "A:5:8" "B:3:4"
```

Explanation: `"DESCRIPTION(.)[^:]*"` matches the word `DESCRIPTION`, then a single character (`.`) which is "saved" as a *capturing group* by the parens `()`, then it continues to match non-colon characters `[^:]`, as many as possible (`*`). It replaces the full match with the first (`\\1`) capturing group.

You can play with it here to understand better: https://regex101.com/r/Sc7oC1/1